# Symfony2 Routing annotation gets url encoded

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, twig

I've playing around with annotations in Symfony2.5 and am struggling to output a nice clean url like this:

```
.../display&type=foo&id=1
```

What I always get is:

```
.../display%26type=foo%26id=1
```

Why is Symfony2 url encoding this?

My controller looks like this:

```
/**
 * Displays content
 *
 * @Route("/display/type={type}&id={id}", name="content_display")
 * @Template(...)
 */
public function displayAction($type, $id = null) {
...
}
```

my twig template has:

```
<a href="{{ path('content_display', {'type': type, 'id': entity.id}) }}">{{ entity.id }}. {{ entity.name }}</a><br />
```

So I've tried to add `|raw` and autoescape off tags described [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html). But no luck so far, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/display/type={type}&id={id}`

...is not a valid URL... you'd have to replace that second slash with a `?`:

`/display?type={type}&id={id}`

That said, the route is meant for *path* replacement -- not *parameter* replacement.

I'm pretty certain that if you change that to simply `/display`, when you try to render the URL with your key-value map, then Symfony will add those as parameters, since it can't find those keys in the path itself.

*Edit:*

Confirmed via [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-with-query-strings):

> The generate method takes an array of wildcard values to generate the
>   URI. But if you pass extra ones, they will be added to the URI as a
>   query string.

Comment: You're right! But still i get this: `/display%3Ftype=foo%26id=1` which is still url encoded. And if I remove the @Route annotation completely symfony2 says type not found

Comment: your 'confirmed via documentation' part refers to generating uri within a controller and not twig right?

Comment: The Symfony framework is big on code reuse, so I imagine that the Twig `path()` call probably makes the exact same method call as the `->generateUrl()` call. The next paragraph in that documentation says that URL generation inside a template "is done just as before", which I take to mean that it also does parameter replacement for keys that it does not find in the path.

Comment: just tried that, and it says: exception: couldn't find path. Not sure how these wildcards work and i can't seem to find the code that dies the generateUrl part.

Comment: Hmm... This is definitely the right answer, but I think there's something else going on. This comment chain is getting a little lengthy, so feel free to open a chat.stackoverflow.com room, or meet me in the #symfony channel on IRC.